# How to unit test exception thrown in TypeScript class's constructor in JestJs

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, exception, jestjs, assertion

I am building some application in `NestJs`, therefore the default unit test framework is `JestJs`. Assume I have following class My.ts

```
export My {
    constructor(private myValue: number) {
       if (myValue ==== null) {
           throw new Error('myValue is null');
       }
    }
}
```

I have created my unit test class My.spec.ts

```
import { My } from './My';

describe('My', () => {
    fit('Null my value throws', () => {
        expect(new My(null)).rejects.toThrowError('myValue is null');
    });
});
```

I use the command `npm run test` to run the unit tests, instead of getting what I expected I had a failure to complain the code in my `My` class constructor that an exception is thrown.

What is the proper way to write unit test code in Jest to test the exception logic in constructor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After I did my research following codes work for me

```
import { My } from './My';

describe('My', () => {
    fit('Null my value throws', () => {
        expect(() => {new My(null);}).toThrow('myValue is null');
    });
});
```