# How to test throw new HttpException in unit test Nest.js

Tags: unit-testing, testing, nestjs

I'm trying to test a service in my Nest.js app. In some of my methods of this service I have some cases where I throw new HttpException depending of the context.

I'm trying to write unit tests of these methods and I don't know how to test cases where I throw HttpException.

I've tried this code:

```
it('Shound return error for a non existing id provided', async () => {
      await expect(service.getUser('false Id')).rejects.toThrow(new HttpException('This user does not exist', 404));
});
```

But I received:

```
Expected the function to throw an error matching:
      [Error: This user does not exist]
    Instead, it threw:
      Error: This user does not exist
```

Does anyone already encounter this use case ?

Comment: What error are you throwing in `service.getUser()`? `NotFoundException` or `HttpException`? Note, that you can also test for the error message only with `toThrow('This user ...')`

Comment: I'm throwing HttpException in service.getUser().
I've tried to test like this :

```await expect(service.getUser('false Id')).toThrow('This user does not exist');```

or like this as well :

```await expect(service.getUser('false Id')).rejects.toThrow('This user does not exist');```

But none of these to solution seems to work.

Comment: I've finally decide to not test throw HttpException in unit testing but in E2E testing

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54206825/3910390

Answer (score 28):

Duc answer works but if you want some prettier way you might like this,

```
 it('should return null when update', async () => {

  await expect(controller.updateById({ id: 'some id' }, {}))
  .rejects.toThrowError(NotFoundException);

});
```

Answer (score 14):

Simply do this:

```js
  it('should return null when update', async (done) => {
    jest.spyOn(service, 'updateById').mockResolvedValue(null)

    try {
      await controller.updateById({ id: 'some id' }, {})
    } catch (error) {
      expect(error).toBeInstanceOf(NotFoundException)
      done()
    }
  })
```

Comment: if the function never throws, won't the test still pass? since expect() will never be called

Comment: @TomRyan of course bro :). this is just a sample. If you want to mock throw. try `mockRejectedValue`

Comment: @Tom Ryan: Try `expect.assertions(1)`before the `try/catch`. That ensures that exactly one assertion was executed.

Answer (score 1):

I had a particular case here where I wanted to check the status code of a HttpException so M.abdelrhman answer was not sufficient. Additionally Duc answer will lead to the test passing incorrectly if the `getUser` never throws. So for your original case checking for the error code and the message of the http response I would use this:

```
let hasThrown = false;
try {
    service.getUser('false id');
} catch(error) {
    hasThrown = true;
    expect(error).toBeInstanceOf(HttpException);
    expect((error as HttpException).getStatus()).toBe(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    expect((error as HttpException).getResponse()).toBe('This user does not exist');
}

expect(hasThrown).toBe(true);
```

With the additional flag ensuring the `getUser` function throws at all